# Terminal does not source .zshrc with custom colors for ls and cd command

Tags: terminal, zsh, colors, autocomplete, oh-my-zsh

I customized the directory and file colors for `ls` and `cd` + `TAB`. Here is my configuration.

---

**My configuration**

My system environment.

```
Ubuntu 10.10
zsh 4.3.10 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
oh-my-zsh // http://git://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh.git
Terminal
```

My .zshrc in $HOME.

```
// .zshrc
echo "Sourcing $0."
ZSH=$HOME/.oh-my-zsh
ZSH_THEME="josh"
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
```

A custom zsh script in ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/completion.zsh

```
// completion.zsh
echo "Sourcing $0."
# Same completion colors when using cd as with ls.
zstyle ':completion:*:default' list-colors ${(s.:.)LS_COLORS}
zstyle ':completion:*:*:*:*:*' menu yes select
```

A custom zsh script in ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/theme-and-appearance.zsh

```
// theme-and-appearance.zsh
echo "Sourcing $0."
export LS_COLORS='di=1;34:ln=35:so=32:pi=0;33:ex=32:bd=34;46:cd=34;43:su=0;41:sg=0;46:tw=1;34:ow=1;34:'
```

---

**The problem description.**

When I open the Terminal for the first time 3 files are sourced. Notice, that `.zshrc` does appear but **not** with its path nor file name.

```
Sourcing zsh.
Sourcing /home/john/.oh-my-zsh/custom/completion.zsh.
Sourcing /home/john/.oh-my-zsh/custom/theme-and-appearance.zsh.
```

Using the `ls` command the directory listing looks as expected. Though, when I use the `cd` command and `TAB` for autocompletion directory colors are not the same as with `ls`.

Then I source the configuration once again. Notice, this time `.zshrc` does appear with its full path and file name. I am not sure whether this contributes to the problem explained here.

```
$ . ~/.zshrc 
Sourcing /home/john/.zshrc.
Sourcing /home/john/.oh-my-zsh/custom/completion.zsh.
Sourcing /home/john/.oh-my-zsh/custom/theme-and-appearance.zsh.
```

Now both `ls` and `cd` + `TAB` use the same colors.

---

**Question**

How do I have to change my configuration that the customization is loaded as soon as I open the Terminal application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in the order the files are sourced. `LS_COLORS` must be defined before you run `zstyle ':completion:*:default' list-colors ${(s.:.)LS_COLORS}`.

You can fix this by renaming the files to something like `00theme-and-appearance.zsh` and `01completion.zsh`.

Comment: Damn. I did not see that. Thank you! Do you know a "nicer" solution besides renaming the files?

Comment: @JJD If you want to keep it all in separate files then renaming them to start with numbers is a common practice to ensure files load in the correct order.

Comment: I thought it could get difficult if dependencies are this way this time but for another case the are the other way around. Then renaming files would no longer help and I would need to extract definitions to another file. Is there something like a **forward declaration** like in programming languages?